# Null child data structures after JSON deserialization

Tags: c#, json, class, deserialization

I have an object that has a property which is a List of other custom objects.
It actually drills down many tiers of custom object properties, but let's just look at the last 3 levels of the object.

```
{
    "version" : {
        "version_data" : [ {
            "version_value" : "6.06"
        }, {
            "version_value" : "7.10"
        }, {
            "version_value" : "8.04"
        }, {
            "version_value" : "8.10"
        } ]
    }
}
```

So my classes look like so:

```
public class Version
{
    [Required()]
    public Version_Data version_data { get; set; }
}
public class Version_Data
{
    [MinLength(1)]
    public List<Version_Data_Item> items { get; set; }
}
public class Version_Data_Item
{
    [Required()]
    public string version_value { get; set; }
}
```

I was able to extract one version_data_item

```
{
     "version_value" : "6.06"
}
```

and if I deserialize that JSON I am able to call something like: `deserializedObject.version_value` and it returns 6.06

The problem I run into is the upper levels. For example, I then extract the "Version_Data" object from the data

```
{
    "version_data" : [ {
        "version_value" : "6.06"
    }, {
        "version_value" : "7.10"
    }, {
        "version_value" : "8.04"
    }, {
        "version_value" : "8.10"
    } ]
}
```

that deserializes into a Version_Data (no exceptions raised at least), but when I debug it says the list is `null`.

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your version_data should be called items:

```
{
    "items" : [ {
        "version_value" : "6.06"
    }, {
        "version_value" : "7.10"
    }, {
        "version_value" : "8.04"
    }, {
        "version_value" : "8.10"
    } ]
}
```

Comment: naming doesn't matter does it? I should be able to call my class properties as I wish right?

Comment: Only if you add attributes to tell the parser how to map the properties. There is no way to know that version should be mapped on items with any help.

Comment: I feel silly. That was it. Since the data comes in from another source I altered my classes to call the list version_data instead of "items", debugged, and the list is populated. So your comment about mapping attributes raises a new question. what would that attribute look like to map version_data to items so I can leave my classes as-is

Answer (score 0):

For generation C# from JSON you can use very helpful web [generator](http://json2csharp.com/).

Your correct models are here:

```
public class VersionData
{
    public string version_value { get; set; }
}

public class Version
{
    public List<VersionData> version_data { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Version version { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: that is the same class structure minus me calling the top level RootObject. A generator will call the Vendor RootObject, but like I said, these objects are the last 3 levels of a much deeper branch of custom objects.

Comment: Please look to your `Version_Data` class. Yout property is called as `items`. There is mistake. The correct name for the property is `version_data`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Newtonsoft's JSON? The structure does not look correct. Unless you use custom parser, the structure should be like this:
https://app.quicktype.io?share=Olvtc5B3C1zg7hy2CJgp